# How can I plot a mathematical expression of two variables in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a time- and depth-varying function, simplified to:

```
def f(z,t):
    return np.exp(-z)*np.sin(t-z)

z = np.linspace(0,3000,num=3001)
t = np.arange(0,40000,4000)
```

I want to plot the the result for all z at each time step in t, resulting in something like this:

[image]

but I don't know how. I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm not used to doing this in python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(z,t):
    return np.exp(-z)*np.sin(t-z)

z = np.linspace(0,5,3001)
t = np.arange(0,40000,4000)

for tval in t:
    plt.plot(z, f(z, tval))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ha, i feel like such a numpty. Thanks!

Comment: well, now you know how to do it, and that's all that's important.