# Plotting a simple equation of two variables in python

Tags: python

I have to plot a graphic of the next equation with two variables, z (depth) and t (time).
It's the first time I work with Python and I've searched examples but they don't work well. Please, could anyone help me?

```
from math import *

def T(z,t):

    T1, T2 = 221, 218
    pc = 533
    k = 0.98
    L = 50
    return sin(pi*z/L)*exp(-k*pi**2*t/(pc*L**2)) + (T2-T1)*z/L + T1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of graphic do you want to plot? Something like `z` on the vertical axis, `t` on the horizontal one? For something like this, there is e.g. `plt.pcolor` or `plt.contour`, but there is also the possibility to make 3d plots of your function.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've tried this code, taken by the next link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812697/how-can-i-plot-a-mathematical-expression-of-two-variables-in-python

And this appears:

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I want a graphic with t on horizontal axis, and z on the vertical.